# Load multiple JS files sequently after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

To speed up the page loading time, I want to load the JS scripts after the page content has loaded.

I found this helpful article which explains how to do this when you have a single JS file: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html

The solution goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "yourSingleJSFile.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

In my case, I have 4 different js files: jQuery, main.js and index.js that are starting with `$(document).ready(...);` and define a function initMap(), and maps.googleapis.com. Therefore I changed the code to

```
function downloadJSAtOnload() {

var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);

var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "/resources/js/main.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);

var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "/resources/js/index.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);

var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***mysecetrkey**&callback=initMap";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Each time I load the page, I find a JS error in the console. There are two errors that I spotted so far:

**First**

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined  index.js:9:5

I don't understand what is happening here. It seems like index.js was included before jquery was loaded. But how come the error is not thrown in main.js?

**Second**

> validValueError: initMap is not a function

It seems to me that googleapis.com js is already loaded but index.js is missing (since I define function initMap() there).

---

How can I force the scripts to load sequently after the page content has loaded?

Comment: Is `jQuery` being referred anywhere in your loaded scripts ?

Comment: take a look at http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Could it be that the order of loaded js is turned around? so that google apis is first and jquery is last.

Comment: @Rayon I don't think it is referred (I am not sure what it means). I just start the js files with `$(document).ready(...)` I thought that is enough

Comment: @Focki no, the order is exactly as stated in the question.

Comment: When I was faced with this problem, I ended up creating a function that takes a list of modules, and recursively adds a call back to each to load the next module when the previous one had finished loading. It only allowed for sequential loading, but it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts have dependencies towards each other you need to make sure that the dependencies loads first. You can nest the script loading like so:

```
var jqueryElement = document.createElement("script");
jqueryElement.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js";

var mainElement = document.createElement("script");
mainElement.src = "/resources/js/main.js";

var indexElement = document.createElement("script");
indexElement.src = "/resources/js/index.js";

var googleApiElement = document.createElement("script");
googleApiElement.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***mysecetrkey**&callback=initMap";

// add the first script element
document.body.appendChild(jqueryElement);

jqueryElementElement.onload = function () {
  document.body.appendChild(googleApiElement);
}

googleApiElement.onload = function () {
  document.body.appendChild(mainElement);
  document.body.appendChild(indexElement)
}
```

I'm just guessing your dependency order.